# Create react app multiple ports for same app

Tags: localhost, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

My React app (made on CRA) is running on `localhost://3000`. Now, for some testing purposes, I want to be able to **run the SAME app on multiple ports**. I am doing this to simulate multiple devices (so that each device has different instance of `localStorage` and `indexeddb`). How can I achieve this so that I can run the same app on, say, ports `3000`, `4000`, `5000` and `6000`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the npm library called concurrently.  Found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

here is a snippet of your npm run commands so you can run either or both

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js --ignore client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```